# Password auth fails when connecting to RDS Postgres using credentials generated by AWS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to connect to an RDS Postgres database from an ECS instance, but I keep getting `error: password authentication failed for user`. Both are configured using the AWS CDK. I'm only supplying the database username and letting AWS generate a password which is supplied to the ECS instance through a secret env var. I'm logging the env vars in the ECS instance and I can see that it is receiving the database connection info including the generated credentials.

Here is my app code

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import * as Koa from "koa";
import * as Knex from "knex";

dotenv.config();
const { env } = process;
const port = parseInt(env.PORT || "3000", 10);

function getDatabaseConnection(): Knex.Config["connection"] {
  const {
    DATABASE_URL,
    DATABASE_HOST,
    DATABASE_NAME,
    DATABASE_CREDENTIALS,
    DATABASE_PORT = "5432",
  } = env;

  if (DATABASE_URL) {
    return DATABASE_URL;
  }

  if (!DATABASE_HOST)
    throw new Error("Missing required env var: DATABASE_HOST");
  if (!DATABASE_NAME)
    throw new Error("Missing required env var: DATABASE_NAME");
  if (!DATABASE_CREDENTIALS)
    throw new Error("Missing required env var: DATABASE_CREDENTIALS");

  const { username, password } = JSON.parse(DATABASE_CREDENTIALS);

  return {
    host: DATABASE_HOST,
    user: username,
    password: password,
    port: parseInt(DATABASE_PORT, 10),
    database: DATABASE_NAME,
  };
}

main();
async function main() {
  const databaseConnection = getDatabaseConnection();

  console.log(`Connecting to database:`, databaseConnection);

  let db: Knex | null = Knex({
    client: "pg",
    connection: databaseConnection,
    acquireConnectionTimeout: 5000,
  });

  await db.raw("SELECT 10 + 15").catch((error) => {
    console.log("Test query failed", error);
    db = null;
  });

  const app = new Koa().use(async (context) => {
    try {
      context.response.body = {
        hello: "world",
        queryResult: db ? await db.raw("SELECT 10 + 15") : null,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      context.response.body = {
        error: { ...error, message: error.message },
      };
    }
  });

  await new Promise((resolve) => app.listen(port, resolve));

  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
}
```

And my AWS CDK stack

```
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import ec2 = require("@aws-cdk/aws-ec2");
import ecs = require("@aws-cdk/aws-ecs");
import cdk = require("@aws-cdk/core");
import { RemovalPolicy } from "@aws-cdk/core";
import rds = require("@aws-cdk/aws-rds");
import ecsPatterns = require("@aws-cdk/aws-ecs-patterns");
import path = require("path");
import { Port, InstanceClass, InstanceSize } from "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2";
import { Secret } from "@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager";

const app = new cdk.App();
const stack = new cdk.Stack(app, process.env.STACK_NAME || "HelloWorld");
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(stack, "MyVpc", { maxAzs: 2 });
const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(stack, "Cluster", { vpc });

const port = 3000;
const databasePort = 5432;
const databaseUser = "app";
const databaseName = "app_db";

cluster.addCapacity("cluser_capacity", {
  instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.T2, InstanceSize.MICRO),
  maxCapacity: 1,
});

const database = new rds.DatabaseInstance(stack, "AppDatabase", {
  vpc,
  engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.POSTGRES,
  instanceClass: ec2.InstanceType.of(
    ec2.InstanceClass.T2,
    ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO
  ),
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  databaseName: databaseName,
  masterUsername: databaseUser,
  deletionProtection: false,
  port: databasePort,
});

const apiService = new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
  stack,
  "AppService",
  {
    cluster,
    publicLoadBalancer: true,
    taskImageOptions: {
      environment: {
        PORT: port.toString(),
        DATABASE_PORT: databasePort.toString(),
        DATABASE_HOST: database.dbInstanceEndpointAddress,
        DATABASE_USER: databaseUser,
        DATABASE_NAME: databaseName,
      },
      secrets: database.secret
        ? {
            DATABASE_CREDENTIALS: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(
              database.secret
            ),
          }
        : {},
      containerPort: port,
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "local-image")
      ),
    },
  }
);

database.connections.allowFrom(apiService.service, Port.tcp(databasePort));

app.synth();
```

Why isn't the username/password generated by RDS working?

Comment: Have you tried connecting using the `psql` command line?

Comment: I'm trying, but I can't seem to connect. I switched the RDS security group to allow anything in on port 5432 and enabled "publicly accessible", but I just timeout when I connect locally. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong here. Cloudformation is handling most of the setup, password generation etc. And I can see the database connection info being logged to cloudwatch.

Comment: From a CDK/CF perspective, everything looks good. Does the created secret contain all DB info? You can check this in Secrets Manager console.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this issue upon creation, it could be that you did not name your database. The name is NOT the same as the instance and AWS defaults to a non-named database.

In the AWS Console, navigate to RDS > Databases > your_database > Configuration

[Is the "DB name" field populated?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsU24.png) If it is not, delete this database and recreate it.

In the creation menu, at the very end, [look under "Additional Configuration". Add an "Initial database name" of your choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j5EU.png). This is now your database name.

[Now you can use this database name to connect via boto3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RVoW.png)